# C# Help with a basic pedagogic example of a BackGroundWorker process populating a DataGridView

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

Scenario:

I have a windows form that holds a `DataGridWiew` with 3 pre-defined columns.
I have 3 variables declared outside the function and assigned to inside the function.
I have a function that enumerates stuff and puts it in the 3 columns, line by line:

```
string VARIABLE1;
string VARIABLE2;
string VARIABLE3;

private void FunctionEnumerateStuff()
{
    foreach (StuffObject STUFF in StuffCollection)
    {
       VARIABLE1 = STUFF.SubStuff1.ToString();
       VARIABLE2 = STUFF.SubStuff2.ToString();
       VARIABLE3 = STUFF.SubStuff3.ToString();
       DatagridWiew1.Rows.Add(VALUE1, VALUE2, VALUE3); 
    }
}
```

What I want to do, is to execute this function from a `BackGroundWorker` process, so that the GUI of the application will be smooth and responsive.
I have read up on backgroundworkers but I am having trouble relating, because all examples seems to be of entirely different scenarios and most of them are overwhelmingly complex.

Can some helpful pedagogic soul help me and others with a very basic example of how to get this to work in the simplest way possible.
Thanks.

Comment: What is the thing that is taking up so much time?  Why make it asynchronous?  Do you have tens of thousands of rows?  Are you having problems NOW with choppiness in the UI?   Maybe you could show your actual code, if that's the case.  The code you show here won't compile.

Comment: I chosed not to be specific about the code and WHY I want to use a solution with a backgroundworker.
I chosed a "fake code" just to illustrate the problem and hopefully get a pedagogic answer back, and not a workaround.

I chosed to formulate my question this way because I actually want to learn by a basic example, not have someone else write the solution in code for me.
I chosed this non specific example, so that hopefully many others out there that seems to be struggeling with similar confusion can relate and learn from it as well.

Comment: You confuse us with your strange words!  Pedagogic: of, relating to, or befitting a teacher or education :)

Answer (score 1):

I would use something like this (very sketchy and untested):

```
  private void bgw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        var list = new List<SomeRowType>();

        foreach (StuffObject STUFF in StuffCollection)
        {
            VARIABLE1 = STUFF.SubStuff1.ToString();
            VARIABLE2 = STUFF.SubStuff2.ToString();
            VARIABLE3 = STUFF.SubStuff3.ToString();
            //DatagridWiew1.Rows.Add(VALUE1, VALUE2, VALUE3);
            list.Add(new SomeRowType(VALUE1, VALUE2, VALUE3));  //probably meant: VARIABLEn
        }
        e.Result = list;
    }

    private void bgw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error != null)
        {
        }
        else
        {
            var list = (List<SomeRowType>)e.Result;
            DatagridWiew1.DataSource = list;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you Henk! 
I will try your example tomorrow. To late for coding right now :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example:

```
class Form1 : Form
{
    private BackgroundWorker Worker { get; set; }

    public Form1()
    {
        Worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        Worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        Worker.DoWork += OnWorkerDoWork;
        Worker.RunWorkerCompleted += OnWorkerRunWorkerCompleted;

        // at some point start the worker.
        Worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    void OnWorkerDoWork(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach(var data in someData)
        {
            // if cancelled
            if (e.Cancelled)
                return;

            AddDataToColumn(someData.Var1, someData, Var2, someData.Var3);
        }
    }

    void OnWorkerRunWorkerCompleted(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private delegate void AddDataToColumnDelegate(string var1, string var2, string var3);
    private void AddDataToColumn(string var1, string var2, string var3)
    {
        // check if cross-thread operation
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            Invoke(new AddDataToColumnDelegate(AddDataToColumn), var1, var2, var3);
            return;
        }

        // Add data to column
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(var1, var2, var3);
    }
}
```